# Fill the matrix at same position by averaging every inputs instead of replacing by the last input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I have two arrays, `aaa` represents the row index of matrix `ref` and `bbb` represents values to fill into `ref`.

```
ref = np.zeros(shape=(4,2))
aaa = np.array([1,1,2,1,3]) # row index
bbb = np.array([1,9,2,5,3]) # value

# At column 0; row 1, fill 1. row 1, fill 9. row 2, fill 2. row 1, fill 5. row 3, fill 3.
ref[aaa,0] = bbb

print ref
>>[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 5.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.]
 [ 3.  0.]]
```

For the row index 1, it has 3 values 1, 9, and 5. I want the average of them as (1+9+5)/3 = 15 instead of filling by the last 5. I think of `np.append()` each of them and `np.mean()` at the end.

```
ref[aaa,0] = [ref[aaa,0]].append(bbb)
```

But this way returns `nan`.

Or

```
ccc = np.array([])
ref[aaa,0] = np.append(ccc, bbb)
```

The row one is still 5 by this way. How can I use `np.append()` here or is it any other fast way to get average instead of replacing?

Comment: FYI `[].append(bbb)` doesn't work as you expect as `.append()` modifies `[]` but doesn't *return* something. Also doesn't really make sense; why would you `[].append(stuff)` instead of just wrap it into another list with `[bbb]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do some aggregation based on `aaa` first and then assign the aggregated values to `ref`, something like below:

```
def avg_by_group(aaa, bbb):
    idx = np.argsort(aaa)
    aaa_sort = aaa[idx]
    bbb_sort = bbb[idx]
    diff_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.ediff1d(aaa_sort, to_begin=-1))
    group_sizes = np.diff(np.concatenate((diff_idx, [aaa.size])))
    avg = np.add.reduceat(bbb_sort, diff_idx)/group_sizes
    return aaa_sort[diff_idx], avg

idx, avg = avg_by_group(aaa, bbb)
ref[idx, 0] = avg
ref

#array([[ 0.,  0.],
#       [ 5.,  0.],
#       [ 2.,  0.],
#       [ 3.,  0.]])
```